# Foursquare categoryId search and photos

Tags: ios, objective-c, foursquare

I'm making a Foursquare API call that returns specified venues in a given area. So in my API call I pass in the parameters of a categoryId and a lat and long. I'm trying to find out if I can get all the photos associated with each returned venue within this same call or do I have to make a separate call and pass in the venue specific id?. Here is what my current url for my venue search call looks like:

```
 "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=44.7681,-85.6222&categoryId=4bf58dd8d48988d14b941735&v=20130815&client_id=XXXXXX&client_secret=XXXXXX"
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the API documentation for FourSquare, there is a separate API call that is required to retrieve a photo(s) based on the venue id.

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/VENUE_ID/photos
```

Comment: Thanks. I had seen that. I was just wondering if there was a way to add a parameter in my current call so I didn't have to make two API calls.